# Creating an object that will hold 108 models

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data frame that contain var ( 21 explanatory variables and 1 dependent variable)

in addition, I have created 2 vectors that split the 21 explanatory variables:
9 and 12 in the following manner (all of them are variables in my data frame named "completesubset") :

```
PersColumns <-  c("religious","E","A","C","N","O","NFC","tsc","se","rumination","depression","ls")

fellingColumns <-  c("valence","arousal","angry","anxious","disapp","surprise","wanting","selfother","control")
```

now, I want to get an object that will hold 108(12*9) models (linear mixed model).
I created an empty list,  double loop on the 2 vectors and each model was added to the list using append function:

```
resultsList <- list()
for(i in 1:length(PersColumns)) {
  for (j in 1:length(fellingColumns)) {
    lmerfit <- lmer(meaning ~ (1|Subject)+PersColumns[i]*fellingColumns[j],data=completesubset)
    resultsList<- append(resultsList, lmerfit)
  }
}
```

I received the following error:

> Error in model.frame.default(data = completesubset, drop.unused.levels = TRUE,  :
>     variable lengths differ (found for 'PersColumns[i]')

Anyone know and can help?
and in general, Is there a better way to achieve this object?

Comment: Your model formula mixes formulas and strings. Instead, create the model formula as a single string: `model_formula = paste("meaning ~ (1|Subject) + ", PersColumns[i], " * ", fellingColumns[j])`. Then, `lmerfit <- lmer(model_formula, data=completesubset)`.

Comment: Also, I think you want `resultsList <- append(resultsList, list(lmerfit))`

Comment: as ever, `?reformulate` is useful

Comment: @eipi10, many thanks!